# JQuery dialog box issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using a UI dialog box to display a message.

It works well in Firefox and Google Chrome.  However, when I test in IE versions the dialog box doesn't open.

Can any one tell what real problem is?

I had pasted my code below:

```
function check_selected(c) {
    var count = c - 1;
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('plan');
    for ( var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].disabled) {

            if (radios[i].checked) { // checked

                $('#planalert').dialog({
                    modal : true,
                    autoOpen : true,
                    title : "Plan",
                    width : 650,
                    height : 150,
                    show : "blind",
                    hide : "scale",
                });

                var c = 0;

            } else {
                var c = 1;
            }
        }

    }
    ;

    if (c == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the trailing comma from the options object you're passing `dialog`:

```
$('#planalert').dialog({
    modal:true,
    autoOpen: true,
    title:"Plan",
    width:650,
    height:150,
    show: "blind",
    hide: "scale" // <-----
});
```

Internet Explorer will choke on the extra comma, while other browsers may not.

Also, remove the semicolon (`;`) at the end of the `for` loop ending brace:

```
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    /* snip */
} // <--- semicolon not necessary
```

Additionally, you are attempting to define `c` multiple times inside of your function. You are passing it in to the function so your `var c = ...` statements actually aren't having the effect you intend. You should either use another variable (which I would recommend rather than mutating the parameter you are passed), or remove the `var` statements from inside the `if` block.

Additionally, your loop is really only setting `c` for the last, disabled radio button. Is this what you intended?

Anyway, here is how I would re-write it (without attempting to fix the logical error above). Be sure to use tools like [JsHint](http://www.jshint.com) to check your JavaScript for probems:

```
function check_selected(c){
    var count=c-1;
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('plan');
    var isChecked = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].disabled) {
            if (radios[i].checked){ // checked
                $('#planalert').dialog({
                    modal:true,
                    autoOpen: true,
                    title:"Plan",
                    width:650,
                    height:150,
                    show: "blind",
                    hide: "scale"
                });
                isChecked = 0;

            } else{
                isChecked = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return isChecked;
 }
```

Comment: IE may chock on the comma, but removal of the semi-colon is irrelevant to the solution.

Comment: @EliranMalka: My solution is attempting to make the asker's code syntactically correct, so actually removing the semicolon *is* relevant to the solution.